# Slider in admin not shown in shopping experiences

Tags: shopware6

the slider is not shown in "Landing Page" in "Shopping experiences".
It is blank like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22OzR.png)

Somebody told me by executing: `bin/console assets:install` it should be shown.
But it does not.
I have also tried: `./bin/build-administration.sh`
But it is still not shown.

Do you have an idea why not?

It may be shown in version 6.4.4.0 but after updating to 6.4.14.0 it is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run all migrations?: `./bin/console database:migrate --all core`

It could be the case, you are missing data from them.